# I want change "li" background color with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have a to do app made by Angular. The data comes from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos. And I want that when I press the Done button, the background color of that "li" will also change. How can I do this?

Here is the Html

```
<input
  (keyup.enter)="createPost(title)" #title
  type="text" class="form-control">
<ul class="list-group">
  <li
  *ngFor="let post of posts"
  class="list-group-item">
  <button
    (click)="updatePost(post)"
    class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="button">
    {{post.completed ? 'Done' : 'Not ready'}}
  </button>
  <button
    (click)="editPost(post)"
    class="btn btn-dark">
    Edit
  </button>
  <button
    (click)="deletePost(post)"
    class="btn btn-danger">
    Delete
  </button>
  {{ post.title }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here is the update function

```
  updatePost(post) {
    this.http.patch(this.url + '/' + post.id, JSON.stringify({ completed: !post.completed })).subscribe(response => {
      post.completed = !post.completed;

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ngClass to toggle a class based on the post status

```
<input
  (keyup.enter)="createPost(title)" #title
  type="text" class="form-control">
<ul class="list-group">
  <li
  *ngFor="let post of posts"
  [ngClass]="post.completed?'list-group-item list-group-item-success':'list-group-item'">
  <button
    (click)="updatePost(post)"
    class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="button">
    {{post.completed ? 'Done' : 'Not ready'}}
  </button>
  <button
    (click)="editPost(post)"
    class="btn btn-dark">
    Edit
  </button>
  <button
    (click)="deletePost(post)"
    class="btn btn-danger">
    Delete
  </button>
  {{ post.title }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass to update the color of li. [ngClass]="{'highlight-post': post.completed}"